# app-routing generates triggers a new instance of auth service

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

when I call this.authService.login() in my admin-login component it logins to firebase and the userData stores the uid within it. I can verify this by calling this.authService.isLoggedIn() which returns true along with my uid in the console. I can also call this.authService.isLoggedIn() in other components and still get the same uid without calling this.authService.login(). The problem is where app-routing.module.ts calls canActivate from the authGuard it generates a new instance of auth.service.ts and this.authService.isLoggedIn() returns false as well as the uid gives me a null value as if I never logged in. How do I keep auth.service.ts a singleton, I added the providedIn: 'root' into the the Injectable.

> Auth.service.ts

```
import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
}
)
export class AuthService {
  private user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  private userData = null;
  constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user = auth.authState;
    this.userData = this.user.subscribe(user => {
      this.userData = user;
    });
  }
  login(email: string, password: string): void {
    this.auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(value => {
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('that didnt work', err.message);
      });
  }
  logout(): void {
    this.auth.signOut();
    this.isLoggedIn();
  }
  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    console.log(this.userData.uid);
    if (this.userData.uid != null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

> auth-guard.service.ts

```
import {CanActivate, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable(
  {
    providedIn: 'root'
  }
)
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, public authService: AuthService) {}

  canActivate(): boolean {
    console.log(this.authService.isLoggedIn());
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

> app-routing.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {GalleryListComponent} from './gallery/gallery-list/gallery-list.component';
import {GalleryItemComponent} from './gallery/gallery-item/gallery-item.component';
import {PhotoItemComponent} from './gallery/photo-item/photo-item.component';
import {UploadGalleryComponent} from './admin/upload/upload-gallery/upload-gallery.component';
import {UploadPhotoComponent} from './admin/upload/upload-photo/upload-photo.component';
import {AdminLoginComponent} from './admin/login/admin-login/admin-login.component';
import {AuthGuardService} from './services/auth-guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: AdminLoginComponent},
  {
    path: 'admin/upload/gallery',
    component: UploadGalleryComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  }
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

> admin-login.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-login',
  templateUrl: './admin-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-login.component.sass']
})
export class AdminLoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  login(): void {
    this.authService.login();
  }
  logout(): void {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think its creating a new instance of the AuthService?

Comment: when I call console.log in auth.service.ts to print out the uid it gives me a different value when I trigger the isLoggedIn method from admin-login versus when the canActivate triggers it in the app-routing

Comment: I doubt it's a different instance. It's set to be provided in the root module so it will be the same through your entire app. I am guessing things aren't happening in the order that you think due to the asynchronous nature of the code. I can't say for sure because I don't have all of your code, but I would guess that the  userData isnt set in time for the auth guard to see it.

Comment: I realized that manually typing in a new route caused hay trigger but if I navigate using routerLink it returns the same key